# Unity3d Facebook AppRequest filter

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project for IOS i use 
FB.AppRequest(
    message: "somedesc",
    title: "sometitle",
    callback:appRequestCallback                                                                                      );
I want  filter and show only friends who don't install app, but filters = ["app_users"] and
 excludeIds = "someIdValue" not working

How solved this problem

(I use Facebook Unity SDK, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity)

Comment: What do you use? Facebook unity SDK?

Comment: Yes, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
// "app_non_users" will list friends that haven't installed the game yet
List<object> filter = new List<object>() { "app_non_users" };
// Then, call the API with this filter. Enjoy!
FB.AppRequest("Test Message", null, filter, null, 0, string.Empty, string.Empty, this.HandleResult);
```

In the **examples** that are provided within the Facebook SDK for Unity, there's a scene called **AppRequests**. From there, I've seen a class named AppRequests.cs, in which you can find several examples on how to use these app requests.
Note: To try this examples, make sure to add all FacebookSDK provided scenes to your build settings scenes. Test them in device.

Answer (score 0):

FB Unity SDK documentation says that filters are currently supported:

[Filter are currently not supported for mobile devices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Apprequest)

You should probably get list of friends first with a request like this with [FB.API method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.API):

```
FB.API ("/me/friends?installed=false", HttpMethod.GET, Callback, null);
```

Comment: But how i can use this list in "FB.AppRequest", because i want to show "facebook dialog invite friends" where only not installed app friends

Comment: The request I listed will get a list of friends who didn't install the app; use to show invite dialog.

Comment: "use to show invite dialog", but how i can use it. For show dialog i use FB.AppRequest and i don't know where connect ListFriendsDontInstall, because method FB.AppRequest have not any parameters for this filter